URL Redirect but preserves only any part of URL, its possible?
Whell, the example is simple, i've a web what shows a elearning courses catalog named privado.recursosimpulsa.com/catalogo_hijo/56
The proporuse of this web is, modifiying last parameter, serve to diferent clients, for example:
privado.recursosimpulsa.com/catalogo_hijo/56 <- One client
privado.recursosimpulsa.com/catalogo_hijo/1363 <- Another client
The app changes desing depens parameters entered, like logos, colors, etc.
Now, I wish to create different subdomains for these clients, like
privado.recursosimpulsa.com/catalogo_hijo/56 -> example1.recursosimpulsa.com privado.recursosimpulsa.com/catalogo_hijo/1363 -> example2.recursosimpulsa.com
With frame redirect works but i've a litte problem. For example, any course detail like this url for client 56
privado.recursosimpulsa.com/product_detail_child/id_product=38273/client=56
and I want that in the brownser show example1.recursosimpulsa.com/product_detail_child/id_product=38273/client=56,
and can share this link and works (actually, return 404 not found, logical why example1.recursosimpulsa.com/product_detail_child/idproduct=38273/client=56 does not exist)
It's is possible with .htaccess or another url-rewriting technique? Thanks in advance.
I've tried with frame redirect and .htaccess 301 redirect
